# how to declare sql query in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am running a mysql insert query from my python script and I am running into the following error  -

```
jobsummaryfile = '/home/abcd/projects/starling/daily_job_summary/'+ starling_date +'.tsv'

    conn = connect_db()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE " + jobsummaryfile + " INTO TABLE daily_job_summary FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4) set (jobname=@col1,queue=@col2,maphours=@col3,reducehours=@col4)")
conn.close()
```

The error i am getting is -

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/home/abcd/projects/starling/daily_job_summary/2014_02_17.tsv I' at line 1")
```

It is picking up the I at the end and that is causing it to fail. How do i get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message shows you, that the parsing not ending with the blank (showing you the "I" from "INTO" next).

You have to (single-)quote your filename, so compose the SQL string with double quotes to embed the `'` around filename

`obsummaryfile = "'/home/abcd/projects/starling/daily_job_summary/" + starling_date + ".tsv'"`

Does this help?

Comment: i fixed this issue on my side...I need help with one more thing...I want to modify the above query to insert few more variables from the script into the same table.